# Extra space in between UISearchController and SearchResultsTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I am using `UISearchController` in objective-c for ios 9 and facing a very unusual issue , Please see the figure below:

[image]
I tried all sort of things with the `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` 
and reframing the view, but nothing works, can anybody help regarding this??

Below is the code how I set up my UISearchController

```
 UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultsViewController"];

    self.searchController=[[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater=self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation=NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Enter city";
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.searchTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation=YES;
```

Comment: The screenshot is helpful.  Please also provide code showing how you setup `UISearchController` and its search bar, as the space does not appear to be the only problem.

Comment: In your view controller's attribute inspector is Adjust Scroll View Insets checked ?
If it is you can either uncheck it in the attribute inspector or programmatically with [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
You can keep this property checked if you adjust your table view constraints to have its top space to its superview constant to 0 and not to top layout guide

Comment: added the setup code, Please look into it, and let me know if I am doing it wrongg

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?